# How can i connect UITableView to my Appdelegate.m?

Tags: ios, appdelegate

> > ```
> > - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
> > {
> >     MainViewController *rootViewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
> >     _naviControl = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
> >     self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
> >     [self.window addSubview:_naviControl.view];
> >     self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
> >     [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
> >     return YES;
> > }
> > ```

In my `AppDelegate` ..!
Connect to `MainViewController.m`

Comment: It would help to include a reason why you would want to do this - could you please include details of your problem?

Comment: hmmm..! i mean to to connect UITableView to Appdelegate !! am try to develop IOS without storyborad !! so i need to connect to appdelegate but am try to search still no answer that i want

Comment: not quite a good idea to manage table in AppDelegate.

Comment: You'd better slow down, take a break and begin from the very first step in iOS development by using a book. I would recommend "Beginning iOS 7 Development". http://www.apress.com/9781430260226

Comment: Also extremely helpful are the iTunes University courses, in particular the more recent Stanford University lecture series [prepared by Paul Hegarty](https://itunes.apple.com/au/course/developing-ios-7-apps-for/id733644550)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AppDelegate is not a UIViewController so connecting a UITableView to it conflicts with the MVC principles as described here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/MVC.html

what you want to do is make your MainViewController's view have a tableView as a subview

something like this:
(in MainViewController.m)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.feedTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.feedTableView.dataSource = self;
    self.feedTableView.delegate   = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.feedTableView];
}
```

Comment: how to set frame of it !!

Comment: you can set it to self.view.bounds

Comment: Thank ! i can do it now !!